# Opening two new JFrames! Why is this happening?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

This code checks the username and password then opens a new JFrame if they are correct. However, two identical JFrames are opened and I am clueless as to the reason.

```
public void checkLogin(String x, String y){
        if (x.equals(loginCredentials[0]) && y.equals(loginCredentials[1])){
            dispose();
            task1ExampleSC o2 = new task1ExampleSC();
            o2.setVisible(true);
            o2.setSize(600,650);
            o2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }else{
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    private class loginAC implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String usernameText,passwordText;
            if (e.getSource()==login){
                usernameText = username.getText();
                passwordText = password.getText();
                checkLogin(usernameText,passwordText);
            }else if(e.getSource()==cancel){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `task1ExampleSC o2 = new task1ExampleSC();` creates a new instance during the handling of an event, and apparently there are multiple events triggering the code.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I posted the event handling code with the method creating the new object. That method is not called anywhere else in my code. I did a search of the code to make certain.

Comment: Certainly, the loginAC ActionListener is being called twice for some reason and this creates 2 instances of `task1ExampleSC`. What is linked to this ActionListener?

Comment: All sorted now, thank you.

Comment: *"opens a new JFrame"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) In this case, a log-in would usually be handled by a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show how you add the listeners to the buttons, but presumably you have something like this:

```
login.addActionListener(new loginAC());
```

Does this line appear more than once in your code? Or is it possible that this line runs more than once? If so, more than one listener will be added to the login button, meaning that more than one `ActionEvent` will be dispatched when the login button is clicked; and if the username and password are both correct, that will result in more than one new window opening.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was driving me insane. I have multiple buttons, did some copy and paste to add the listeners and didn't change one of the names!